# Business Layer - UI communication

Tags: c#, .net

Taking the following cases in consideration.
Witch one would you prefer and why?
Suggestions appreciated.

1. Using Delegates

   ```
   private void cmdDelete_enterClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {               
       var accountManager = new BLAccountManager();
       accountManager.OnAccountInUse = (msg) => MessageBox.Show(msg);

       accountManager.OnConfirmation = (msg) =>
       {
           var dialogResult = MessageBox.Show(msg);
           return (dialogResult == DialogResult.OK);
       };

       accountManager.DeleteAccount(selectedAccountId);
   }
   ```

   ---

   ```
    public class BLAccountManager
    {

   public Action<string> OnAccountInUse;
   public Func<string, bool> OnConfirmation;


   public void DeleteAccount(string accountId)
   {
       var bookingsUsingAccount = GetBookingsUsingAccount(accountId);
       if (bookingsUsingAccount.Count > 0)
       {           
           OnAccountInUse("msg");
           return;
       }
       BankAccount account = GetAccount(accountId);
       if (OnConfirmation("confirm"))
       {
           account.Delete(false);
       }
   }
   }
   ```
2. Using Interfaces

   ```
     public interface IUICallback
     {
        void SendMessage(string message,string caption);
            bool Confirmation(string message,string caption);
     }
   ```

   ---

   ```
   public class WinFormsUICallback : IUICallback
   {
     public void SendMessage(string message, string caption)
     {
       MessageBox.Show(message, caption, MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                       MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
     }

     public bool Confirmation(string message, string caption)
     {
       DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(message);
       return result == DialogResult.OK;
     }
   }
   ```

   ---

   ```
     private void cmdDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
           IUICallback uiCallback = new WinFormsUICallback();
       var accountManager = new BLAccountManager(uiCallback);  
       accountManager.Delete(selectedAccountId);
     }
   ```

   ---

   ```
     public void Delete(string accountId)
     {
       BookingList bookingsUsingAccount =     bookingManager.GetBookingsUsingAccount(accountId);
       if (bookingsUsingAccount.Count > 0)
       {       
               _uiCallback.SendMessage(msg, caption);
               return;
       }

       if (_uiCallback.Confirmation(confirmationMessage, caption))
           {
              account.Delete(false);
       }
      }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

A third option is to use continuations:

```
public void DeleteAccount(string accountId, Action<string> OnAccountInUse, Func<string,bool> OnConfirmation)
{
    var bookingsUsingAccount = GetBookingsUsingAccount(accountId);
    if (bookingsUsingAccount.Count > 0)
    {           
        OnAccountInUse("msg");
        return;
    }
    BankAccount account = GetAccount(accountId);
    if (OnConfirmation("confirm"))
    {
        account.Delete(false);
    }
}
```

edit: adding the usage, similar to the cases in the question

```
private void cmdDelete_enterClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{               
    var accountManager = new BLAccountManager();

    Func<string,bool> OnConfirmation = (msg) =>
    {
        var dialogResult = MessageBox.Show(msg);
        return (dialogResult == DialogResult.OK);
    };

    accountManager.DeleteAccount(selectedAccountId,
                                 (msg) => MessageBox.Show(msg),
                                 OnConfirmation);
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Unfortunately I have a few other parameters that I need to pass to DeleteAccount and I think that adding the additional delegates  to the parameters list would be to much.

Comment: I do quite like this approach.  The parameters could always be passed in via a DTO if there are extra ones than just the two....

Comment: tnx for this post

Answer (score 1):

I think I like the combination of your third option with that supplied by Dan.  I've made some other changes which may or may not be better.  Not really sure.  My aim was to have the Delete set status callbacks only i.e. success, failure while the UI event handler handled the confirmation requirements.

If anything, I would always suggest using .Any() over .Count() > 0 operations as although a minor thing could have unexpected have performance benefits on large collections.  And if anything I personally think it reads a bit nicer.

```
  public class CallBackArgs
  {
      public string Message { get; private set; }
      public string Caption { get; private set; }

      public CallBackArgs(string msg, string caption)
      {
         Message = msg;
         Caption = caption;
      }
  }

  public interface ICrudCallback
  {
     void SendMessage(CallBackArgs args);
     void OnSuccess(CallBackArgs args);
     void OnFailure(CallBackArgs args);
  }

  private void cmdDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     WinFormsUICallback= new WinFormsUICallback();

     if (_uiCallback.Confirmation("Please confirm deletion is required", "Confirm"))
     {
        var accountManager = new BLAccountManager();  
        accountManager.Delete(selectedAccountId, (ICrudCallback)uiCallback);
     }
  }

  public void Delete(string accountId, ICrudCallback uiCallback)
  {
    BookingList bookingsUsingAccount = bookingManager.GetBookingsUsingAccount(accountId, ICrudCallback uiCallback);

    // When doing .Count() > 0 comparisons always try and use .Any() 
    if (bookingsUsingAccount.Any())
    {       
         uiCallback.OnFailure(new CallBackArgs("Account in use", "In use"));
    }        
    else
    {
        // Delete could throw an exception, return an error string, return a status
        // code, or in my case return bool.  Either way we handle it
        if(account.Delete(false))
        {
           uiCallback.OnSuccess(new CallBackArgs("Delete succeeded","Success"));
        }
        else
        {
           // add error message appropriate from delete here?
           uiCallback.OnFailure(new CallBackArgs("Somethings gone wrong!","Oops"));
        }
    }
  }
```

Well that's my 2cents for what it's worth.